# ':ProjectName' could not be found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have this error when creating Modules without copying files
`settings.gradle` :

```
include ':libraries:ProjectB'
project(':ProjectB').projectDir = new File('libraries/ProjectBRoot/ProjectB')
```

and in

```
dependencies {
  .....
  compile project(':ProjectB')
}
```

Error :

```
Error:Project with path ':ProjectB' could not be found.
```

Does any guys meet this issue?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `include ':ProjectB'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `settings.gradle` should be:

```
include ':ProjectB'
project(':ProjectB').projectDir = new File('libraries/ProjectBRoot/ProjectB')
```

Then your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  .....
  compile project(':ProjectB')
}
```